# Bash: Syntax error near unexpected token `then'

Tags: linux, bash, if-statement

the error is at line 21...

```
if [ $weight1 -gt $weight2 ];
    then echo "Weight 2 should be greater than Weight 1."
else
    if [ $weight1 -ge 20 ] && [ $weight1 -le 39 ];
        then echo "Weight 1 is bike."
    else 
        echo "Weight 1 is either bicycle, car, van or lorry."
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Which line is 21?

Comment: The code, as posted, works for me.  Please post the code that fails.

Comment: we don't know where the problem is? and where the line 21 is?

Answer (score 6):

I done\'t see the issue, on my tests `then` keyword is worked for your case, anyway some noted on your code:

1. Put `then` on the line of `if` operator:

   ```
   if [ $weight1 -ge 20 ] && [ $weight1 -le 39 ]; then
   ```
2. Enclose your variables into quotes:

   ```
   if [ "$weight1" -ge 20 ] && [ "$weight1" -le 39 ]; then
   ```
3. I recommend to use `-a` key, instead to two calls to `[` app:

   ```
   if [ "$weight1" -ge 20 -a "$weight1" -le 39 ]; then
   ```

**NOTE:** The error `Syntax error near unexpected token 'then'` can rise up mostly in a few cases:

1. When you specify `then` keyword outside of `if` case:

   ```
   weight1=21
       then echo "Weight 1 is bike."
   else
       echo "Weight 1 is either bicycle, car, van or lorry."
   fi
   ```
2. when youve specified `then` twice:

   ```
   if [ "$weight1" -ge 20 -a "$weight1" -le 39 ]; then
   then echo "Weight 1 is bike."
   ```
3. when you've put `then` to improper place, for example, after the `else` operator:

   ```
   else
   then
       echo "Weight 1 is either bicycle, car, van or lorry."
   fi
   ```

Comment: @Dropout I hadn't seen `;` pardon me

Answer (score 0):

just

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

first line:
    add `#!/bin/bash`

then do:

```
./test.sh
```

It is working whithout problem